# SUM interfering with COUNT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Using this query, I get the result I need of how many orders each customer has placed. However, when I use the SUM(OrderLine.ActualPrice) in the SELECT field and use an inner join to link the Order table to the OrderLine table which contains the price. The COUNT results are skewed, as the OrderLine table contains multiple OrderNo of the same Order, since one order can contain multiple products.

How do I keep the COUNT to the result I have with this query, while putting in the SUM query for the Total Purchase Amount of their orders?

```
SELECT C.custno, 
       companyname, 
       Count(customerorder.orderno)AS 'Total Orders', 
FROM   customer C 
       INNER JOIN customerorder 
               ON customerorder.custno = C.custno 
GROUP  BY C.custno, 
          companyname
```

MODIFIED QUERY WITH INCORRECT RESULT

```
SELECT C.custno, 
       companyname, 
       Count(customerorder.orderno)AS 'Total Orders', 
       Sum(orderline.actualprice) 
FROM   customer C 
       INNER JOIN customerorder 
               ON customerorder.custno = C.custno 
       INNER JOIN orderline 
               ON customerorder.orderno = orderline.orderno 
GROUP  BY C.custno, 
          companyname
```

This is the query I tried to use and received the skewed COUNT results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two basic options.

**Use DISTINCT**

```
SELECT C.custno, 
       companyname, 
       Count(DISTINCT customerorder.orderno)AS 'Total Orders', 
       Sum(orderline.actualprice) 
FROM   customer C 
       INNER JOIN customerorder 
               ON customerorder.custno = C.custno 
       INNER JOIN orderline 
               ON customerorder.orderno = orderline.orderno 
GROUP  BY C.custno, 
          companyname
```

*Note:*

In a comment on another question you say that this scews te result still.  This seems to imply that the same `orderno` can appear in more than one `customerorder` record.  Is that correct?

**Use a sub-query to make the join 1:1 instead of 1:many**

```
SELECT C.custno, 
       companyname, 
       Count(customerorder.orderno)AS 'Total Orders', 
       Sum(orderline.actualprice) 
FROM   customer C 
       INNER JOIN customerorder 
               ON customerorder.custno = C.custno 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT orderno, SUM(actualprice) AS actualprice
                     FROM orderline 
                 GROUP BY orderno)
               ON customerorder.orderno = orderline.orderno 
GROUP  BY C.custno, 
          companyname
```

Comment: Is there an added benefit to using DISTINCT over subquery or Vice versa?

Comment: When I do not use DISTINCT the result is skewed. The OrderNo can appear on multiple instances of the OrderLine table.

Comment: @RandyB. - I prefer the SubQuery as using DISTINCT often masks other mistakes *(When I see DISTINCT I often wonder if it's a hack to correct a mistake in a bad way)*.  Also, sometimes it's more performant - you should trial both with your data to compare.  *[You say that using distinct you get the right results, yet on the other answer you say that you don't?]*

Comment: I read his wrong, using DISTINCT was correct. Thank you both though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT C.custno, 
       companyname, 
       Count(Distinct customerorder.orderno)AS 'Total Orders', 
       Sum(orderline.actualprice) 
FROM   customer C 
       INNER JOIN customerorder 
               ON customerorder.custno = C.custno 
       INNER JOIN orderline 
               ON customerorder.orderno = orderline.orderno 
GROUP  BY C.custno, 
          companyname
```

Use Count on DISTINCT order numbers

Comment: That's exactly the one I have tried, but it skews the results of the COUNT query.

Comment: Such as I know a certain company has placed 6 orders, but with the SUM and Join, I get the COUNT result of 11 orders for that company.

Comment: I read that wrong, you're correct. Sorry about that. I didn't use DISTINCT.